# How to use JSON correctly in an HTML email

Tags: html, json, encoding, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have an HTML-Email, that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Do not change next section</p>
    <pre>
{
  "from": "..",
  "to": "..",
  "statistic": {..},
  "creationDate": ".."
}
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Sending this Email content with *Outlook-Exchange* it encodes the `JSON` inside the `HTML` to:

```
{
  &quot;from&quot;: &quot;...&quot;,
  ..
}
```

Sending it with *Mailcatcher* it works (`"from": "2019-08-01",..`).

I use `javamail` for sending and receiving emails.

Comment: I don't think email providers accept `<pre />` tag.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Outlook-Exchange.  You could try forcing the text to be base64 encoded by setting the Content-Transfer-Encoding header to "base64".